# Data from one textview getting overwritten on another textview in relative layout

Tags: android

I have used relative layout and scrollview in my xml file.
When i click "Get Meaning " button i get the description of command but the data gets overlapped.Plz suggest some solution.
My layout xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/img7"
     >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="490dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/house1" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Enter Unix Command"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" 
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Start Typing Here........"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:text="Get Meaning"

        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/searchpic1"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button2"

        android:src="@drawable/book1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Cympac Software Solutions Pvt Ltd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#228b22"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/smallicon"/>





</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and on emulator its like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Orabig* said put only `textview2` in ScrollView and and it should be above to the `textview3`. And Use `RelativeLayout` as a parent layout. Follow the code from Other two answers.I hope it will work

Comment: Can someone explain what makes this answer better than mine ? (or even differnet ?) :o

Comment: :) I think difference is with Parent layout.

Comment: Well, ok, but he already HAD a RelativeLayout as a parent. I just posted the changes to do... Oh, well, nevermind...

Answer (score 1):

add property of `layout_above` for textview
change code like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
/>
```

and then add scrollable property for that textview

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

it will scrolls automatically if the text requires more space than available.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your TextView into a ScrollView

```
 <ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
   >
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text=""
      android:textColor="#FF0000"
   />
</ScrollLayout>
```

Comment: If i am taking textview inside scrollview the xml file is not getting parsed and i am not getting the description